# Set Image as background (width of screen) of webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a one page scrolling site, I want to use an image for the background of my home page. I've tried several ways but I can't seem to get the content infront of the image, only below it.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {  
    background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
</style>

<title>Digital Portfolio</title>

<meta name="description" content="Portfolio of my work">
<meta name="keywords" content="Sara Cook, portfolio, digital media">
<meta name="author" content="Sara Cook">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcuticon"/>
<link href="img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
<link href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"sizes="72x72"/>
<link href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"sizes="114x114"/>
<link href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"sizes="144x144"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Your title is asks about setting a background image but your first paragraph asks about getting content to show in front of a background image, also some css or a fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: background-size: 100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "head" tags, place this:

```
<style>
    body {  
        background: url(bgimage.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

replace bgimage.jpg with the path to your image file.

Comment: Thank you, should the style tags be anywhere in particular in the head tags? as I've placed this and the image isn't showing

Comment: Can you please post all the text in your head tags so that I can see what you are working with?

Comment: Most likely if it is not showing, it is because the path is incorrect. If you have the image in a folder named "images" for example, you must change "bgimage.jpg" to be "images/bgimage.jpg" or whatever your image is named.

Comment: <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    body {  
        background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
</style>

<title>Digital Portfolio</title>

<meta name="description" content="Portfolio of my work">
<meta name="keywords" content="Sara Cook, portfolio, digital media">
<meta name="author" content="Sara Cook">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcuticon"/>
<link href="img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
<link href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"sizes="72x72"/>
<link href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"sizes="114x114"/>
<link href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"sizes="144x144"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-style.css"/>
</head>

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't realise it'd look like that when i posted it, is there another way i can send it to you?

Comment: You can edit your original question and add the entire document text as you did before.

Comment: Put the style block I gave you below the style sheet links. Make it the last thing in the head tags. That way the other body blocks in your CSS files, do not overwrite it. Let me know.

Comment: if this was a working solution, please select it as the answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Set the image as a background on the `html` element. Full explanation [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/BSXgb/2/

Code:

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Digital Portfolio</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Portfolio of my work">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Sara Cook, portfolio, digital media">
    <meta name="author" content="Sara Cook">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcuticon"/>
    <link href="img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
    <link href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"sizes="72x72"/>
    <link href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"sizes="114x114"/>
    <link href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"sizes="144x144"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="sixteen columns clearfix">
            <div class="four columns alpha">
                <h1>Sara Cook</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="offset-by-six columns omega">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#home_page">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about_page">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#graphic_page">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#photography_page">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        <article id="pages">
          <section id="home_page" class="sixteen columns clearfix">
            <div class="offset-by-ten columns">
              <p> From Kent, Uk. My name is Sara Cook and I'm</p>
              <p> a student at the University of Kent, Studying</p>
              <p> Multimedia Technology and Design.</p>
              <p> Please browse my portfolio and feel free to contact</p>
              <p> me. I hope you enjoy my site.</p>
            </div>
          </section>

          <section id="about_page"></section>
          <section id="portfolio_page"></section>
          <section id="contact_page"></section>
        </article>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
html {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This way doesn't seem to be working for me. Do I need to add anything to my index.html for this to work?